# Android Studio Emulator no apps can perform this action

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXwBM.png)I make instagram clone app very long coding. I trying app and ı want chosing picture in gallery.But galery not open. and show no apps can perform this action. Why this error?

And ı try my mobile phone and its worked. Only emulator problem.How can ı fix this?

Comment: install gallery on emulator simple

Comment: Add code with question which u r using for opening gallery .

Comment: gallery last version.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have set a wrong MIME type, try to change the MIME type to `*/*`

Check also if you have the last version of Android Emulator

Comment: what is MIME? yes android emulator last version .

Comment: It's a string that define the data type handled by your intent.  Use [this method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent?hl=bg#setDataAndType(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String)) to set it.

Comment: Try setting it to your intent like this : `your_intent.setType("*/*");`

Comment: ı try but thats not working this solution:(

Comment: ' val intent = Intent(this@AddPostActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                    intent.type = "*/*"
                    startActivity(intent)
                    finish()'